# php limit view per one user

Tags: php, mysql, sql

First i must say this my second question (first was closed becouse i did not explain my question very good)

I am building databse that should be used by our 50-60 employes. In our base we have many customers (1row = 1customer). Idea is when employe open page, it should display one customer, but if another employe open same page it should show another customer (i want to avoid situations if 2 employe press refresh button at the same time, the page sould not display same customer.

i have this php code for getting data out of base, but if i push refresh on same time it will give me same result on 2 PC. How can i avoid that

In table telesales_anc i have column 'Lock_ID' and php update it with '1' when page is open

Is there any function that 'hold' the connection to the row or something like that? I try to google it but i only find some solution with timer (but i think this is a bad idea, and still 2 emlpoyes can open in same time)

```
$MSISDN = "SELECT MSISDN FROM telesales_anc WHERE Lock_ID != 1 LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($MSISDN);

while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
$IDcheck = "SELECT ID FROM telesales_anc WHERE '{$row['MSISDN']}' = MSISDN";
$result_IDcheck = $mysqli->query($IDcheck);

while ( $row = $result_IDcheck->fetch_assoc()) {
$lock_ID = "UPDATE telesales_anc SET Lock_ID = 1 where '{$row['ID']}' = ID";
$result_ID = $mysqli->query($lock_ID);

}}
```

Comment: What is the problem behind this? Why can't I see the same customer as somebody else?

Comment: becouse i want to avoid that two employe will call same customer, that database contains customer information and employes call them. so for example we have 10000 customer that need to be call. But i want to avoid taht two employe call same customer.

Comment: i am not very sure but you don't need your 2nd query, you can get msisdn and id from the first query and if you fetch one update the Lock_ID immedietly. Still it can be race-condition but atleast it will decrease the chance

Comment: When one employee opens a customer, update MYSQL record field with "locked" status and ignore it on other people. To prevent user don't unlock it back, check all locked statuses when you open the page and remove locked status if locked for more than x amount of time.

Comment: but when "UPDATE telesales_anc SET Lock_ID = 1 where '{$row['ID']}' = ID" the UPDATE is only to 'Lock_ID' and it stay in locked, so theoreticly it is locked, but i tested it with two PC and if page refresh at same time it will give me same result. Obviously one user update Lock_iD with 1 and other user too.

Answer (score -1):

I add a usleep() for a very short time to wait other users lock and a small change at the 2nd sql `AND Lock_ID!=1` so if other user locked it you wont fetch this one, please be aware that you need some loops for retries to fetch unlocked one

```
$MSISDN = "SELECT MSISDN FROM telesales_anc WHERE Lock_ID != 1 LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($MSISDN);

usleep(rand(100000,300000)); // we are sleeping randomly between 0.1 - 0.3 seconds for waiting the other users lock
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $IDcheck = "SELECT ID FROM telesales_anc WHERE '{$row['MSISDN']}' = MSISDN AND Lock_ID != 1";
    $result_IDcheck = $mysqli->query($IDcheck);

    while ( $row = $result_IDcheck->fetch_assoc()) {
        $lock_ID = "UPDATE telesales_anc SET Lock_ID = 1 where '{$row['ID']}' = ID";
        $result_ID = $mysqli->query($lock_ID);

}}
```

Comment: i try this method, but still if i press refresh at same time it will give me same results, i try to delay one refresh a 1second and then it worked. But there is a chance that any of employes refresh at same time (maybe small chance, but still)

Comment: is it possible to solve this by creating session that contain row_id, so if seassion with specific row id exist it will create new one. Is this a good way of thinking?

Comment: Solving race-conditions are up to an `atomic methods/functions` which php is lack of it. I mean Operationg system file locking, or memcache add method these are atomoics also Java has their own atomic metohd type,  we need some 3rd party help in php also you can try to add a lock in memcached server its reay easy way to setup one and use native memcached client:
`Memcached::add() is similar to Memcached::set(), but the operation fails if the key already exists on the server. ` http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.add.php